# Select a file to be tracked by git

Tags: git, github

I would like git to track a file, `site.db`, that is currently not tracked because I ran `git rm --cached site.db`

Since running that command I have made a few changes to the file and I would like to push it to a remote repository.

How can I do this?

When I run `git status`, it returns:

````
git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 52 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    denise/site.db```

I'm worried that if I `push` then `denise/site.db` will be deleted, when I actually want to push it!
````

Comment: If you actually want to keep tracking it, why did you delete it? It sounds to me like you decided to shoot off your leg, and is now asking how to stand on it. Can't you simply discard or edit the commit that deletes that file, so that it doesn't delete it?

Comment: If you want it tracked, don't run `git rm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do git add of that file it should readd it